# UIAutomator viewer - incorrect UI XML Snapshoot

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-tools, uiautomatorviewer

I've downloaded the SDK to try the uiautomationviewer.bat. It is works fine with native apps like 'calculator':
[image]

But, it shows incorrect position of elements in some games, viewer just loose focus or so, for example:
[image]

Environment:

- OS - Windows 7 Pro / Android 7.0
- Real Device - Samsung A510F
- Java - 1.8.0_151
- Android Debug Bridge version - 1.0.39
- SDK version - 26.0.1
- uiautomatorviewer - 25.3.1

Is there some way to find out what is going on (probably logs)? How to get XML with correct position of elements on the not native apps in my case?

Comment: Later, I just install latest SDK + Java1.8 on Win 8 (another workstation) and nothing changes. I tried to kill adb process, restart device and PC but fail. Also, I tried to get snapshot from other game and the same things - incorrect positions. There are no additional info in uiautomatorviewer logs.
It is quite strange because uiviewer works well with apps predefined by OS(clock, calc etc.)
Probably I miss something? Thank you!

Comment: I have found out that first (root) (0)FrameLayout [1080,1920] - on the first screehshoot.
But on the game's screen first (root) (0)FrameLayout [810,1440] I think it is a root cause. Now all I have to do just realise why they are differ.